# Find nearest crop of image within another image

Tags: image-processing, geometric-transform, computer-vision

`ImageAlign[ref, i]` works well when image `i` is fully contained within the reference image `ref`, but not so well when only a subregion of `i` appears in `ref`. For example:

```
r1 = ResourceFunction["RandomPhoto"][200];
r2 = ResourceFunction["RandomPhoto"][200];
i1 = ImageTake[r2, {120, 160}, {80, 180}];
i2 = ImageTake[r2, {90, 180}, {110, 140}];
ref = ImageCompose[r1, i1];
{ref, ImageAlign[ref, i2]}
```

[image]

How can I get `ImageAlign` to return the region at which they overlap:

```
ImageCompose[ref, {ImageApply[{.5, 1.5, .5}*# &, i2], .5}, {70, 70}]
```

[image]

I've tried using `ImageCorrelate` and `ImageCorrespondingPoints` but can't seem to get it quite right, but I'm sure there's an elegant solution here.

Comment: I get a black image for some reason but I think you'll need something like this: `crsp = ImageCorrespondingPoints[h, ref];
transform = Last@FindGeometricTransform[crsp[[1]], crsp[[2]], TransformationClass -> "Translation"]; ImageTransformation[ref, transform]`

Comment: @flinty Yes, but what I want is to find the rectangle where i2 and ref could intersect if moved and scaled. So you're right I'd want to look at `ImageCorrespondingPoints[ref, i2]`, but unfortunately that is empty.

Comment: Random images are hard because they have so many keypoints, all of low quality. If your image really is a natural image surrounded by noise, I would suggest croping the image, either manually or by algorithm, allowing imageAlign to do its thing.

Comment: Doesn’t need to be random, just replace RandomImage with ResourceFunction[“RandomPhoto”]

Comment: Correct @user5601

Comment: @M.R. Since it doesn't have to be random, and since there is reason to believe that having a non-random background will make the problem easier, please provide an example of that in the question.

Comment: @C.E. Ok, just updated the question

Comment: You see the issue right? The "extra" part of the image confuses `ImageAlign`... We're looking to align *some subregion* of image, which is an additional breakdance on top of it all!

Comment: Perhaps a deep learning approach to image registration can be adapted to this? Will try to give this a go later during the week, if I find time - but figured I'd send two examples of [supervised](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.03798.pdf) and [unsupervised](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1709.03966.pdf) learning along.